# How to set kube-scheduler print log to file

Tags: kubernetes, scheduler

*kubernetes's version is 1.2*

I want to watch the scheduler's log. So how to set kube-scheduler's log print to a file?

The kube-scheduler's configuration is at this path: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.
And the global configuration is at this path: /etc/kubernetes/config.
So we can see these notes:

```
# logging to stderr means we get it in the systemd journal
KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR="--logtostderr=true"

# journal message level, 0 is debug
KUBE_LOG_LEVEL="--v=0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you tail the contents of the service (if running in systemd): journalctl -u apiserver -f

Or if a container, find the container id of the scheduler, and tail with docker: docker logs -f