# How to kubernetes scheduler log file?

Tags: kubernetes, logging

As you know during od scheduling in kubernetes many steps are done and also many messages are printed for example with: `klog.Infof("")`. I would like to check all printed messages and the events happend in scheduler. How I can check kubernetes scheduler log file? `kubectl get events` or `kubectl describe pod`  are not useful for this purpose.

I checked the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891350/how-to-set-kube-scheduler-print-log-to-file), but `journalctl -u apiserver -f`  did not show kuberenets scheduler logs.

Comment: Firstly, you need to know how is set up your scheduler. What process starts your scheduler? Is it systemd? Is it docker? Is it declared as a static pod into the /etc/kubernetes/manifest? Please add this information to your question